# Algorithm to time-sort N data streams

Tags: algorithm, sorting, asynchronous, time, stream

So I've got N asynchronous, timestamped data streams. Each stream has a fixed-ish rate. I want to process all of the data, but the catch is that I must process the data in order as close to the time that the data arrived as possible (it is a real-time streaming application).

So far, my implementation has been to create a fixed window of K messages which I sort by timestamp using a priority queue. I then process the entirety of this queue in order before moving on to the next window. This is okay, but its less than ideal because it creates lag proportional to the size of the buffer, and also will sometimes lead to dropped messages if a message arrives just after the end of the buffer has been processed. It looks something like this:

```
// Priority queue keeping track of the data in timestamp order.
ThreadSafeProrityQueue<Data> q;
// Fixed buffer size
int K = 10;
// The last successfully processed data timestamp
time_t lastTimestamp = -1;

// Called for each of the N data streams asyncronously
void receiveAsyncData(const Data& dat) {
   q.push(dat.timestamp, dat);
   if (q.size() > K) {
       processQueue();
   }
}

// Process all the data in the queue.
void processQueue() {
    while (!q.empty()) {
        const auto& data = q.top();
        // If the data is too old, drop it.
        if (data.timestamp < lastTimestamp) {
            LOG("Dropping message. Too old.");
            q.pop();
            continue;
        }
        // Otherwise, process it.
        processData(data);
        lastTimestamp = data.timestamp;
        q.pop();
    }
}
```

Information about the data: they're guaranteed to be sorted within their own stream. Their rates are between 5 and 30 hz. They consist of images and other bits of data.

Some examples of why this is harder than it appears. Suppose I have two streams, A and B both running at 1 Hz and I get the data in the following order:

```
(stream, time)
(A, 2)
(B, 1.5)
(A, 3)
(B, 2.5)
(A, 4)
(B, 3.5)
(A, 5)
```

See how if I processed the data in order of when I received them, B would *always get dropped?* that's what I wanted to avoid.Now in my algorithm, B would get dropped every 10th frame, and I would process the data with a lag of 10 frames into the past.

Comment: Is your application multithreaded? (And if not, why not?)

Comment: Yes, but the receiving end has to process the data in order. I won't name the specific application, but you could imagine it as being something like N streaming video sources that get drawn to a screen in a time-synchronized way.

Comment: So each source is guaranteed to produce an ordered stream?

Comment: Garunteed to be ordered.

Comment: Why not just set 'K' to 1 or 2?  i.e. Process each datum as soon as possible.

Comment: Suppose I get t = 2 from stream A and process it immediately. Cool. Now I get t = 1 from stream B. Whoops! That's in the past, I can't process it. So I have to drop it. Now I get t = 3 from A, and process it. Now I get t = 2 from stream B. Dropped. See what's going on? Stream B's messages can't ever be processed because its out of sync with stream A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a producer/consumer structure. Have each stream put data into the queue, and a separate thread reading the queue. That is:

```
// your asynchronous update:
void receiveAsyncData(const Data& dat) {
   q.push(dat.timestamp, dat);
}

// separate thread that processes the queue
void processQueue()
{
    while (!stopRequested)
    {
        data = q.pop();
        if (data.timestamp >= lastTimestamp)
        {
            processData(data);
            lastTimestamp = data.timestamp;
        }
    }
}
```

This prevents the "lag" that you see in your current implementation when you're processing a batch.

The `processQueue` function is running in a separate, persistent thread. `stopRequested` is a flag that the program sets when it wants to shut down--forcing the thread to exit. Some people would use a `volatile` flag for this. I prefer to use something like a manual reset event.

To make this work, you'll need a priority queue implementation that allows concurrent updates, or you'll need to wrap your queue with a synchronization lock. In particular, you want to make sure that `q.pop()` waits for the next item when the queue is empty. Or that you never call `q.pop()` when the queue is empty. I don't know the specifics of your `ThreadSafePriorityQueue`, so I can't really say exactly how you'd write that.

The timestamp check is still necessary because it's possible for a later item to be processed before an earlier item. For example:

1. Event received from data stream 1, but thread is swapped out before it can be added to the queue.
2. Event received from data stream 2, and is added to the queue.
3. Event from data stream 2 is removed from the queue by the `processQueue` function.
4. Thread from step 1 above gets another time slice and item is added to the queue.

This isn't unusual, just infrequent. And the time difference will typically be on the order of microseconds.

If you regularly get updates out of order, then you can introduce an artificial delay. For example, in your updated question you show messages coming in out of order by 500 milliseconds. Let's assume that 500 milliseconds is the maximum tolerance you want to support. That is, if a message comes in more than 500 ms late, then it will get dropped.

What you do is add 500 ms to the timestamp when you add the thing to the priority queue. That is:

```
q.push(AddMs(dat.timestamp, 500), dat);
```

And in the loop that processes things, you don't dequeue something before its timestamp. Something like:

```
while (true)
{
    if (q.peek().timestamp <= currentTime)
    {
        data = q.pop();
        if (data.timestamp >= lastTimestamp)
        {
            processData(data);
            lastTimestamp = data.timestamp;
        }
    }
}
```

This introduces a 500 ms delay in the processing of all items, but it prevents dropping "late" updates that fall within the 500 ms threshold. You have to balance your desire for "real time" updates with your desire to prevent dropping updates.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is exactly what I wrote already. This will drop out-of-sync messages all the time. Will modify my question with an example of why this is harder than it appears.

Comment: Artificial delay is totally the right way to go and solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's always be a lag and that lag will be determined by how long you'll be willing to wait for your slowest "fixed-ish rate" stream.

Suggestion:

1. keep the buffer
2. keep an array of bool flags with the meaning:"if position ix is true, in the buffer there is at least a sample originated from stream ix"
3. sort/process as soon as you have all flag to true

Not full-proof (each buffer will be sorted, but from one buffer to another you may have timestamp inversion), but perhaps good enough?

Playing around with the count of "satisfied" flags to trigger the processing (at step 3) may be used to make the lag smaller, but with the risk of more inter-buffer timestamp inversions. In extreme, accepting the processing with only one satisfied flag means "push a frame as soon as you receive it, timestamp sorting be damned".
I mentioned this to support my feeling that lag/timestamp inversions balance is inherent to your problem - except for absolutely equal framerates, there will be perfect solution in which one of the sides is not sacrificed.

Since a "solution" will be an act of balancing, any solution will require gathering/using extra information to help decisions (e.g. that "array of flags"). If what I suggested sounds silly for your case (may well be, the details you chose to share aren't too many), start thinking what metrics will be relevant for your targeted level of "quality of experience" and use additional data structures to help gathering/processing/using those metrics.

Comment: I think this is the closest answer to correct. Will try it and let you know how it goes.